# gcAllowVeryLargeObjects is set but still causing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, gcallowverylargeobjects

I'm a little bit out of ideas. With the following code I try to instace a byte array > than 2GB:

```
var b = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), uint.MaxValue);
```

Every time it will cause an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` excpetion with the message that `arrays larger then 2GB are not supported`.

My App.config is currently the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
      <startup> 
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
      </startup>
      <runtime>
         <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
      </runtime>
   </configuration>
```

Further the target platform of the project is `x64`

I'd be grateful for any ideas. Should there be any information missing I will update the question so as soon as possible.

### Update 1

I also tried `uint.MaxValue`

Comment: An array is indexed with an [int] expression.  You can't index that array, the maximum value of that expression is Int32.MaxValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sanity check, you are trying to allocate 9.223 EB (exabytes) sequential block of memory and that is 9.223×10^9 GB (gigabytes). Simply, but you cannot even do that on x64 machine as some memory is used anyways and that would be maximum.

Instead try to use dynamically growing list:

```
var b = new List<byte>();
```

---

## edit:

The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.' - source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

The effect of gcallowverylargeobjects-element is that you can define multi-dimentsional arrays that exceed 2Gb and in case of other data types you can allocate 2146435071*data_type_size memory. For example int32 consists for 4 bytes, so it would be 8.586 GB (gigabytes).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You're completely right, it's a not-so-sense approach. I've reworked the question. uint.MaxValue causes the same exception and would, in my opinion, instantiate a 4GB array.

Comment: The problem with 4GB is about 2x too much, 'The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.' - source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

Comment: Based on your quote: What then is the purpose of gcAllowVeryLargeObjects? If no object other than arrays is affected, but the index is limited to 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7).

Comment: @MarvinMcFly You can define multi-dimentsional arrays that exceed 2Gb.

Comment: @MarvinMcFly The purpose is that arrays can be larger than 2GB in _size_. E.g. if you have an array of ints: you can now let it have 2bn elements each 4 bytes long and thus the array being 8GB in size.

Comment: Might want to update it as OP has changed from `ulong.MaxValue` -> `uint.MaxValue`

Answer (score 0):

Single-dimensional arrays can't contain more than `int.MaxValue` elements, even though they can be bigger than 2gb with `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` (e.g `new int[int.MaxValue / 2]` is ~4gb). To get around this, you must either create a 2 dimensional array, or use a different type, such as

```
public struct BytePair
{
    public byte First, Second;
}
```

and then create a `BytePair[]` of half the size the equivalent `byte[]` would be

Comment: Or he could just use a ValueTuple, e.g. `new (byte First, byte Second)[2_100_000_000];`.